# is there an other method to show a special sprite from an array

Tags: c#, arrays, variables

I'm making a game using unity and I have this sprite that needs to change the image when upgrading it. I tried to do this:

```
    if (vegPoint == 1)
    { //changes the vegetable so you actually get some visual stuff
        salat.image.overrideSprite = salat2[vegPoint];
    }
```

I tried to use a variable to show the number of the image from the array. but that doesn't work. I​ would do this instead of having 100 lines of code filled with if statements.

Comment: `but that doesn't work.` What **specifically** doesn't work?

Comment: Also this seams to be a framework specific question please explain what are you using.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, hook event when vegPoing variable is changed and then run your code which is written above. in your case, you are checking if vegpoint equals to 1, so it will only work if vegpoint = 1, in any other case it won't do anything.
So do something like this

```
public class OvverrideImgCOntroller : MonoBehaviour {

   public Sprite[] SpritesArr;
   public Image Img;

   private int _vegPoint;
   private bool _UpgradeDone;

   void Update() {
       if (_UpgradeDone) {
           Img.overrideSprite = SpritesArr[++_vegPoint]; // or _vegpoint++ depended on your logic
           _UpgradeDone = false;//make this variable false to prevent upgrade method to execute this code multiply
       }       
   }

   //calling this method for example when UI button is clicked
   public void DoUpgrade() {
       _UpgradeDone = true;
   } 
}
```

Comment: thank you, it helped a lot, but I have one more question. how do I make sure it will load the sprite image when I switch scene. this code you provided to me is for my shop. but when i go out of my shop, and in it again it hasn't loaded the sprite

Comment: Can you explain your problem deeper? And why don't you just change sprite of your image and give up overrideSprite property?